# How to write a http REST service asynchronously

Tags: vert.x

What is the recommended way in vert.x to write an Asynchronous request handler?

In this service, a request processing typically involves calling DB, calling external services, etc. I do not want to block the request handling thread however. What is the recommended way to achieve this using vet.x? In a typical asynchronous processing chain, I would use the request handling thread to emit a message to the message bus with the request object. Another handler will pick this message and do some processing such as checking request params. This handler can then emit a new message to the bus which can be picked up by the next handler which will do a remote call. This handler emits a new message with the result of the call which can be picked up by the next handler which will do error checking etc. Next handler would be responsible for creating the response and sending it to the client.

How one can create a similar pipeline using vert.x?

Comment: just checking in, did you find the answer useful? did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Everything, comprising request handlers for [HttpServer](https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServer.html), is asynchronous, isn't it?

```
var server = vertx.createHttpServer(HttpServerOptions())
server.requestHandler { req ->
    req.setExpectMultipart(true) // for handling forms
    var totalBuffer = Buffer.buffer()
    req.handler { buff -> b.appendBuffer(buff) }
        .endHandler { // the body has now been fully read
            var formAttributes = request.formAttributes()
            req.response().putHeader("Content-type","text/html");
            req.response().end("Hello HTTP!");
        }
    // the above is so common that Vertx provides: bodyHandler{totalbuff->..}
}.listen(8080, "127.0.0.1", { res -> if(res.succeeded()) ... });
```

You just need to (end) write on `req.response()` on your final handler of your pipeline.

For a more stream-like implementation (i.e., not callback-based), you may use [Vert.x Rx](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-rx/java2/)/[ReactiveStreams API](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-reactive-streams/java/). E.g., you may use [Vert.x Web Client](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/) for making requests, possibly using its [Rx-fied API](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/java/#_rxjava_2_api).